# Efficient way of converting terraform JSON schema to AWS API JSON schema

Tags: json, go, terraform

I'm super new to Go and I'm trying to convert a JSON schema which contains terraform specific attribute names to AWS API specific JSON schema in Go.

For example:
The input is of type:

```
{
  "egress": [
    {
      "cidr_blocks": [
        "0.0.0.0/0"
      ],
      "description": "Port 443",
      "from_port": 443,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "to_port": 443
    }
  ],
  "ingress": [
    {
      "cidr_blocks": [
        "0.0.0.0/0"
      ],
      "description": "Port 443",
      "from_port": 443,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "to_port": 443
    }
  ],
  "name": "my_sec_group",
  "vpc_id": "${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"
}
```

And the desired output should be matching the AWS API object which would be something like this:

```
{
  "SecurityGroups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "my_sec_group",
      "IpPermissions": [
        {
          "FromPort": 443,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
              "Description": "Port 443"
            }
          ],
          "ToPort": 443
        }
      ],
      "IpPermissionsEgress": [
        {
          "FromPort": 443,
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "IpRanges": [
            {
              "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
              "Description": "Port 443"
            }
          ],
          "ToPort": 443
        }
      ],
      "VpcId": "${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I have tried till now:**

> **I. Create a generic JSON spec and use it to convert the input JSON to desired output**

My generic JSON spec looks something like this:

```
{
      "aws_security_group": [
        {
          "terraform_attribute": "name",
          "attribute_type": "string",
          "aws_attribute": "GroupName"
        },
        {
          "terraform_attribute": "vpc_id",
          "attribute_type": "string",
          "aws_attribute": "VpcId"
        },
        {
          "terraform_attribute": "description",
          "attribute_type": "string",
          "aws_attribute": "Description"
        },
        {
          "terraform_attribute": "ingress",
          "attribute_type": "list",
          "aws_attribute": "IpPermissions",
          "list_items": [
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "from_port",
              "attribute_type": "string",
              "aws_attribute": "FromPort"
            },
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "to_port",
              "attribute_type": "string",
              "aws_attribute": "ToPort"
            },
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "protocol",
              "attribute_type": "string",
              "aws_attribute": "IpProtocol"
            },
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "cidr_blocks",
              "attribute_type": "list",
              "aws_attribute": "IpRanges",
              "list_items": [
                {
                  "terraform_attribute": "cidr_blocks.value",
                  "attribute_type": "string",
                  "aws_attribute": "CidrIp"
                },
                {
                  "terraform_attribute": "description",
                  "attribute_type": "string",
                  "aws_attribute": "Description"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "terraform_attribute": "egress",
          "attribute_type": "list",
          "aws_attribute": "IpPermissionsEgress",
          "list_items": [
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "from_port",
              "attribute_type": "string",
              "aws_attribute": "FromPort"
            },
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "to_port",
              "attribute_type": "string",
              "aws_attribute": "ToPort"
            },
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "protocol",
              "attribute_type": "string",
              "aws_attribute": "IpProtocol"
            },
            {
              "terraform_attribute": "cidr_blocks",
              "attribute_type": "list",
              "aws_attribute": "IpRanges",
              "list_items": [
                {
                  "terraform_attribute": "cidr_blocks.value",
                  "attribute_type": "string",
                  "aws_attribute": "CidrIp"
                },
                {
                  "terraform_attribute": "description",
                  "attribute_type": "string",
                  "aws_attribute": "Description"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Then I'm using this spec to convert the input JSON to desired output by recursively visiting each block within the input something like this:

```
for key, val := range configCopy {
            for _, detail := range resourceDetails {
                detail := detail.(map[string]interface{})
                if detail["attribute_type"] == "string" && detail["terraform_attribute"] == key {
                    delete(configCopy, key)
                    configCopy[detail["aws_attribute"].(string)] = val
                    break
                } else if detail["attribute_type"] == "list" && detail["terraform_attribute"] == key {
                    delete(configCopy, key)
                    configCopy[detail["aws_attribute"].(string)] =
                        buildListValue(val, detail["list_items"].([]interface{}))
                }
            }
        }

func buildListValue(val interface{}, listItemVal []interface{}) []map[string]interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(val)
    var result []map[string]interface{}
    fmt.Println("Val Kind:", v.Kind(), "Val String: ", v.String())
    valCopy := make([]interface{}, v.Len())
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
            valCopy[i] = v.Index(i).Interface()
        }
    }

    for _, eachVal := range valCopy {
        res := make(map[string]interface{})
        f := reflect.ValueOf(eachVal)
        if f.Kind() == reflect.Map {
            for _, key := range f.MapKeys() {
                fmt.Println("Key:", key.String(), " value:", f.MapIndex(key).Interface())
                for _, listItem := range listItemVal {
                    listItem := listItem.(map[string]interface{})
                    if listItem["attribute_type"] == "string" && listItem["terraform_attribute"] == key.String() {
                        res[listItem["aws_attribute"].(string)] = f.MapIndex(key).Interface()
                        break
                    } else if listItem["attribute_type"] == "list" && listItem["terraform_attribute"] == key.String() {
                        res[listItem["aws_attribute"].(string)] =
                            buildListValue(f.MapIndex(key).Interface(), listItem["list_items"].([]interface{}))
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if f.Kind() == reflect.String {
            for _, listItem := range listItemVal {
                listItem := listItem.(map[string]interface{})
                if strings.HasSuffix(listItem["terraform_attribute"].(string), ".value") {
                    res[listItem["aws_attribute"].(string)] = f.String()
                }
            }
        }
        if len(res) > 0 {
            result = append(result, res)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Where `configCopy` is the input JSON. This approach works, but the problems associated with this approach are:

1. It is a time consuming process as I need to manually create a spec for each resource type.
2. Error prone as the transformation code is completely dependent on the manual spec being defined.

> **II. Tried using some open-source JSON transformers in Go like [kazaam](https://github.com/qntfy/kazaam)**

Project kazaam takes a JSON string and a schema spec as input and produces the result using the given spec very similar to project Jolt.

I tried using a spec like this to convert the above input JSON:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "SecurityGroups.Description": "description",
      "SecurityGroups.GroupName": "name",
      "SecurityGroups.VpcId": "vpc_id",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissions.IpProtocol": "ingress[*].protocol",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissions.FromPort": "ingress[*].from_port",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissions.ToPort": "ingress[*].to_port",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissions.IpRanges.CidrIp": "ingress[*].cidr_blocks[*]",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissions.IpRanges.Description": "ingress[*].description",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissionsEgress.IpProtocol": "egress[*].protocol",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissionsEgress.FromPort": "egress[*].from_port",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissionsEgress.ToPort": "egress[*].to_port",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissionsEgress.IpRanges.CidrIp": "egress[*].cidr_blocks[*]",
      "SecurityGroups.IpPermissionsEgress.IpRanges.Description": "egress[*].description"
    }
  }
]
```

But the result produced was something like the one shown below which is not what I was expecting:

```
{
  "SecurityGroups": {
    "IpPermissionsEgress": {
      "FromPort": [
        443
      ],
      "ToPort": [
        443
      ],
      "IpRanges": {
        "Description": [
          "Port 443"
        ],
        "CidrIp": [
          [
            "0.0.0.0/0"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "IpProtocol": [
        "tcp"
      ]
    },
    "VpcId": "${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}",
    "IpPermissions": {
      "FromPort": [
        443
      ],
      "ToPort": [
        443
      ],
      "IpRanges": {
        "CidrIp": [
          [
            "0.0.0.0/0"
          ]
        ],
        "Description": [
          "Port 443"
        ]
      },
      "IpProtocol": [
        "tcp"
      ]
    },
    "Description": null,
    "GroupName": "my_sec_group"
  }
}
```

Which is not as expected. I may be doing something wrong while constructing the kazaam spec, but I'm not really sure.

Is there any better/efficient way to address this use case? Any suggestions on this would be of great help.